# disabled option "enable wi-fi" Ubuntu 14.04 (i have only wi-fi access at home)

Tags: wireless

I have disabled enable wi-fi function (Ubuntu 14.04). I tried with sudo rfkill unblock all but it doesn't work. I have Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro and Intel Corporation Wireless 7260(rev 6b).
Can you please tell me what to do?

these http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2215044&page=3 I cannot do since I do not have any other Internet acces than wi-fi (but I have another computer)

Comment: Is it hard blocked? If so, rfkill commands will not work. Check your wireless switch and check BIOS settings. If you have dual boot, login to another OS, enable wifi there and reboot back into Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's see if we can get the device unblocked:

```
sudo modprobe -r ideapad-laptop
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

Now is it working? If so, let's blacklist the module:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist ideapad-laptop"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Comment: It's working now! Thank you. Can you tell me what I actually did?:)

Comment: The module _ideapad-laptop_ is supposed to translate key presses, Fn+F2 for example, into action, in this case, turn on the wireless radio. On the Yoga 2 Pro, it is a known issue that it doesn't do wireless so well and the fix is to remove it. We did so and your wireless came to life as expected. Next, we blacklisted it so it doesn't reappear and interfere on boot. I am glad it's working. Please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If You are using Dell laptop and Ubuntu refer below commands :

**sudo modprobe -r dell_laptop

  sudo rfkill unblock all**

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the OP states that they are using a Lenovo Yoga 2 laptop